# OUt of the box ASP.Net Core with react.js project. What calls npm start?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-scripts

I am new tonode and react so bear with me.

I have build the Weather Forecast app using the 'ASP.Net Core with react.js' template . All I am trying to do here is understand the anatomy of the project.

IN the Client App folder I am seeing a package.json file with a 'scripts' section.

```
"scripts": {
"prestart": "node aspnetcore-https && node aspnetcore-react",
"start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"lint": "eslint ./src/" },
```

I am thinking "start" is just a way of referencing the actual node command, so manually typing 'npm run start' would run 'rimraf ./build && react-scripts start' Nothing too complicated there.

My question is, what is calling this when I run from Visual Studio?
For example If I rename start to 'buildconfigstart' (awful name I know), I can manually run npm run buildconfigstart. HOwever, when I run from Visual Studio then the SPA is not loaded, presumably because "something" is still calling npm run start. What is this 'something' and how do I change it to run 'npm run buildconfigstart' ??? Just trying to figure out what goes on under the hood / how this all hangs together. Thanks in advance